# How to add more virtual desktops to fedora mate?

Tags: linux, fedora, mate-desktop

The Fedora (23) Mate comes with 4 desktops.
How can I add more desktops? The manual says "right click on the desktop switcher applet -> settings. and change the amount of available deskops." There is no field to change the amount of desktops!

Answer (score 2):

Just found it in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity). I am using compiz, so i have to change in the compiz settings:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this can easily be changed like described in the manual if you are using **Marco** (*the default window-manager of MATE*):
[image: change settings]
...or open a terminal and type `gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general num-workspaces 20` (*20 is the number of workspaces/virtual desktops you wish; it must be between 1 and 36*).

---

if you use **Metacity** i'm afraid there is no GUI-way to set the number of desktops, but it can be done by opening a terminal and enter `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 20` (*20 is the number of workspaces/virtual desktops you wish; it must be between 1 and 36*).

---

if you want to use **Compiz** have a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/34578/354350

---

### change the window-manager:

to change the window-manager go to the *Control Center* and choose *Desktop Settings*, *Windows* and use the dropdown menu under ***Window Manager***:
[image: Window Manager]
...or simply open a terminal and type `gsettings set com.linuxmint.desktop mate-window-manager marco`.

Comment: if it is not working, first please have a look (and post) which window-manager you are using instead...!